# Iterate trough nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
for id, record in people.items():
    for key in record:
        if record["name"].lower() == "agness":
            print(id)
            print(record[key])
```

After executing code above I get:

```
yDlgcn99xPc19mYXcRmy
Agness
yDlgcn99xPc19mYXcRmy
25
yDlgcn99xPc19mYXcRmy
Female
94cp4hsyZP2BnCh4D34z
Agness
94cp4hsyZP2BnCh4D34z
25
94cp4hsyZP2BnCh4D34z
Female
```

My question is about how to print **id** only once time before person info:

```
yDlgcn99xPc19mYXcRmy
Agness
25
Female
94cp4hsyZP2BnCh4D34z
Agness
25
Female
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for id, record in people.items():
    first = True
    for key in record:
        if record["name"].lower() == "agness":
            if first: print(id)
            print(record[key])
        first = False
```